# Spring boot integration test with multiple data sources getting url cannot be null

Tags: spring-boot

Currently, I am working on spring boot application, we are connecting mysql as part of the main database and H2 Db(in memory) as part of integration testing. Now we have requirement to add two more databases, I am connecting multiple data source by providing multiple data sources in application.properties

```
spring.mys.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://17.27.24.33:3306/my-db
spring.mys.datasource.username=root
spring.mys.datasource.password=1234
spring.mys.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.teradata.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://17.27.24.33:3306/mydb
spring.teradata.datasource.username=root
spring.teradata.datasource.password=password
spring.teradata.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

and when we are having single data source I am able to connect to HSQL in memory db as part for test application.properties with profile test

```
spring.jpa.database: HSQL          
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop          
spring.profiles.active=test
```

After adding second data source my integration testing got failed with below error. Basically, we need to implement integration test for both data sources. appreciate any help, thanks.

Our code in the integration test

```
    @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = { ServiceConfig.class, JWTProtectedWebSecurity.class })
    public abstract class BaseIRTest  {
    }
```

See the error below while running the maven test

```
2017-11-22 12:31:04.479 ERROR 14648 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:649) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:308) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:732) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]
    at
```

Comment: did you create application-test.properties for h2 database?

Comment: Yes i have created application.test properties in java\test\resource folder

Comment: spring.jpa.database: HSQL  
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop   logging.level.org.springframework = ERROR  
logging.level.org.hibernate = ERROR  
logging.level.org.apache.http.wire=ERROR  
logging.level.org.springframework.security=ERROR  

spring.profiles.active=test

Comment: The exception is   

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySqlEntityManager' defined in com.core.config.ServiceConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Comment: Please show your pom file?

Comment: actually its very big, 

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>compile</scope>

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
   <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
  </dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
   <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
  </dependency>

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
   <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
<build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>

    <configuration>
     <argLine>${argLine}</argLine>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <source>${java.version}</source>
     <target>${java.version}</target>

Comment: spring boot multiple data sources is working fine with entity manager/transaction manager in serviceConfig.java file, but while doing maven test, these entity manager/transaction manager are trying to get initiate and gets falied

Comment: does body have any idea on this ? could please help on this